# Is there way to get a static Windows Terminal latest install MSI link from github

Tags: windows, github, terminal

Is there a way to give users a link to the latest version of Windows Terminal msixbundle?
Or even how to get the URL programmatically?

Like pseudo code:

```
location=curl -sI https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/latest | grep location:
version := path.Base(location)
versionNoV := version[1:]
wtfisthis := "8wekyb3d8bbwe"
base_url = "https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/download"
url = fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_%s_%s.msixbundle",
                                    base_url, version, versionNoV, wtfisthis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub doesn't provide an automatic link for the latest release that can be used to directly download a release asset.  In general, you should be careful about trying to do this, since sometimes the latest release is a new major version, bringing in incompatible changes.

However, you can query the GitHub REST API to [find assets related to the latest release](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#get-the-latest-release).  That will contain the proper URLs to use.  However, it is not static.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this is possible for GitHub releases if the released binary has a static filename.

So, for other projects you can simply download the latest release with a fixed URL like: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases/latest/download/youtube-dl.exe. Unfortunately, that will not work with the current release process for Windows Terminal.

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/linking-to-releases

Several people have contributed short scripts to help address this here: https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8